# How to load nginx logs into google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to export all of my nginx access logs to a Google BigQuery table so I will be able to analyze it.

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

You could use fluentd. There is a bigquery plugin for that: https://github.com/kaizenplatform/fluent-plugin-bigquery